# hg: undo checkout of old commit while having local changes

Tags: mercurial, commit

Using `mercurial`, I regularly run into the following problem which I am not able to securely resolve:

1. I commit my changes doing `hg commit -m "my changes"`
2. I edit some file
3. I checkout an old commit doing `hg checkout -r -15`

The problem is that in between (2) and (3), I forgot to first commit my uncommitted changes. `mercurial` then tries to merge my local changes into the old commit.

> How do I undo the checkout in (3) and get back to stage (2)?

This is, I would like to again have the last commit being the commit in (1) and would still like to have the uncommitted local changes in (2).

Answer (score 1):

> How do I

**Short answer**

Nohow

**Longer answer**

You can't restore the exact state of working directory anyway. But you can:

- block `hg up` with dirty working directory (with uncommitted changes): redefine update in aliases as `hg up -c`
- store WIP in [shelve](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension)|[MQ](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension) before update: redefine (again) command as shell-alias with two consecutive commands. Restoring changes still will be you handwork

Comment: I find it wired that one cannot undo a checkout. But I like your way of making it impossible to update a dirty working directory, thanks!